# R, scraping web with xpathSApply

Tags: r, web-scraping

After I parsed a webpage, I can see the xpath like this..

```
gethelp.df =htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
gethelp.df
.
.
....
<div class="lia-message-post-date">
        <a class="lia-link-navigation" id="link_14" href="/t5/Facebook/m-p/3947664">
            <span class="DateTime">
        <span class="local-date">?06-05-2013</span>
        <span class="local-time">09:38 AM</span>
</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and I'd like to grab "06-05-2013" part.

So far I tried these and a bunch of others, but it doesn't work. Can anyone point what I'm missing here?

```
xpathSApply(gethelp.df, "//span[@class='local-time']", xmlGetAttr, "href")
xpathSApply(gethelp.df, "//div[@class='lia-message-post-date']/span", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

Thanks!

Comment: The "06-05-2013" is a value rather then an attribute have you tried xmlValue?

Comment: Thank you. You were right! It was a value rather than an attribute!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xpathSApply(gethelp.df, "//span[@class='local-date']", xmlValue)
```